# Creating multi-send transactions for native chain tokens (MATIC/ETH)

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk

I am building up a multi-send transaction using the `safe-core-sdk` which will then be proposed using the `safe-service-client`'s `proposeTransaction` method.

I am able to do this currently for deployed ERC20's by building up a transaction with the following logic, and then subsequently creating this transaction using the core sdk method `createTransaction`:

```
const transferActions: MetaTransactionData[] = transfers.map(
      (transfer) => ({
        to: transfer.tokenAddress,
        value: '0',
        data: this.getTransferData(transfer.recipientAddress, transfer.tokenAmount),
        operation: 0
      })
    )
```

where `this.getTransferData` gets the encoded function data like so:

```
  private getTransferData(address: string, amount: number) {
    const contractFunctionData = new ethers.Contract(this.tokenAddress, abi)
    return contractFunctionData.interface.encodeFunctionData('transfer', [
      address,
      parseUnits(amount.toString())
    ])
  }
```

How would I go about doing something similar for the native token on a chain? In my case I am trying to build up a multi-send transaction that will send MATIC on Polygon network to multiple addresses. Do I need to get the ABI and address for the native MATIC token, and follow the same steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value` property is the value of the native token. So for the native token transfer, you need to specify the `to` property to the recipient's address, and `value` is the amount of native token you want to send.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Would the `data` param then just be an empty string?

Comment: data param would be `0x` for anyone wondering. courtesy of the gnosis team on discord.